# Знаки препинания в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

*Дружить можно по-разному: кто-то дружит так, что в любой ситуации всё окажется нипочем и никакая преграда не разлучит.*

На мой взгляд запятая перед И не нужна, потому что для обоих предложений слова «в любой ситуации» общие. Так ли это?

Comment: Двоеточие предполагает перечисление. Дружить можно по-разному: кто-то дружит так, а кто-то иначе.

Comment: Здесь  надо учитывать контекст.  Возможно,   о каком-то  варианте дружбы уже говорилось ранее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, **запятая не нужна**, два однородных придаточных связаны одиночным союзом И и имеют общее обстоятельство "в любой ситуации".

Comment: Меня волнует вопрос: какие именно два слова в этом "сложном предложении" выступают в роли "однородных придаточных".

Comment: (1) Дружить можно по-разному:  (2) кто-то дружит так, что (3) в любой ситуации всё окажется нипочем и (4) никакая преграда не разлучит.

Comment: Сложное предложение включает 4 предложения: между 1 и  2, 3, 4 бессоюзная связь, предложения 2, 3, 4  составляют СПП (2 - главное, 3 и 4 - придаточные с двойным  значением (образ действия + следствие).